# What would be the intensity of light reflected on the interface of denser to rarer medium when the critical angle is not achieved?

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction

There is always some amount of light reflected on the interface of the surface of denser to rarer medium. I just want to know, how much of light is actually reflected and how much refracted depending on refractive index of medium. Is there a mathematical formula for a particular refractive index?